# Angular/RxJS 6 - How to unit-test that instructions triggered by a next() throw an exception

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, throw

Before migrating to RxJs6, one of my unit tests was :

```
it('should do what I expect, () => {
  expect(() => {
    myComponent.mySubject.next({message: 'invalid'});
  }).toThrow('invalid is not an accepted message');
})
```

In my component, I subscribe to the subject and call a private method that can  throw an exception. Something looking like that :

```
export class MyComponent {
  //...
  mySubject = new Subject();
  //...
  ngOnInit(){
    this.mySubject.subscribe(obj => this._doSomething(obj))
  }
  //...
  private _doSomething(obj) {
    if ('invalid' === obj.message) {
      throw new Error('invalid is not an accepted message');
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

Since I migrated to RxJs6 this UT does not work anymore (it worked before) and I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I read the migration guide, especially this section : [Replacing synchronous error handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#ex-1), but it is about `subscribe()`, not `next()`...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.

Not sure about the relevance, but it seems to work for me.

I use the angular testing methods `fakeAsync` and `tick` to trigg the emission of the unhandled exception.

Transform :

```
it('should do what I expect, () => {
  expect(() => {
    myComponent.mySubject.next({message: 'invalid'});
  }).toThrow('invalid is not an accepted message');
})
```

into :

```
it('should do what I expect, fakeAsync(() => {
  myComponent.mySubject.next({message: 'invalid'});
  expect(() => tick())
    .toThrow('invalid is not an accepted message');
}))
```

By the way, this trick also makes me sure that if the exception is not thrown, the test will fail.

Comment: @martin : If you dont mind, i'd appreciate your opinion on such a workaround. (In fact, I did not find how to manipulate `window.onerror` or `process.on('error')` handlers in jasmine, it kept on failing)

Comment: I have this error when using your method: `Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of null`

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. In RxJS 5 when subscribing with `subscribe` if you didn't set any `error` handler the error was just re-thrown. That's why your unit test worked before.

But that's not how it works in RxJS 6 because all non-handled errors are re-thrown in `window.onerror` or `process.on('error')` (depending on your environment).

What you could do is making the test async and then checking that one of the handlers above was called:

```
it('should do what I expect, done => {
  process.once('error', () => done());

  myComponent.mySubject.next({message: 'invalid'});
});
```

This is `mocha` style but I guess in Jasmine it's going to be similar.

Actually, what you have is not a very good way to test observable chains because whether an error is handled or not is only subscribers business and not caller's. In other words, you shouldn't test how an emission is handled by subscribers.

It took me a while to find the appropriate commit but read the description here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/cd9626a4f93cac6f631d5a97dd9c9b2aa8e4b5db (it's mentioned also in the [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)).

Comment: Thx a lot for your time and explanations. I am not sure to understand why what I do is wrong (excuse my poor english). I cannot test my private method because IMO this is the component business. This can change over the age and I dont care how it does the magic. What I really want to test are the outputs of my component according to input values. And the subject's entries are one of them (IRL, they come from queryParams). So I do have to subscribe it and this is the only way I have to trig all my private methods. But maybe I am wrong, I am pretty unexperienced in unit testing.

Comment: Also, what bothers me in your workaround is that if the exception is never thrown, the engine gets stuck in the UT and never exits.  But I will clearly consider this track. Thx again!